# There are N strings. Find the index of the most similar (from start) before each one in the smallest number of operations

Tags: c#, performance, compare

"Strings" mean arrays of abstract "symbols", they may but do not have to be the literal text strings. "The most similar" means the longest common part **at start** (this task does not involve very complex algorithms finding all common parts of strings, leading common part is enough). "Before each one" means that each string is compared only with preceeding strings. "Operations" mean elementary operations, if some short and beautiful LINQ call compares each string with each, it performs N * (N - 1) / 2 operations, not one operation.

For example, the input { K, M, G, KG, MG, KMG, KGG, T, KT, MT, GT, KGT, MGT, MTT } must lead to the output { -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 3, 5, -1, 6, 4, 2, 6, 4, 9 }

I have tried this code:

```
//AnyType[][] strings;
var result = new int[strings.Length];
for (var i = 1; i < strings.Length; i++)
{
    int matchIndex = -1, matchLength = 0;
    for (var j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        var length = Math.Min(strings[i].Length, strings[j].Length);
        var k = 0;
        for (; k < length && strings[i][k].Equals(strings[j][k]); k++) ;
        if (k <= matchLength)
            continue;
        matchLength = k;
        matchIndex = j;
    }
    result[i] = matchIndex;
}
```

(This is abstract representation, there may be typos.)

But, of course, this is not optimal, because performs N * (N - 1) / 2 * (3 * K + 6) elementary operations (K is the match length), which is approximately equal to 1.5n<sup>3</sup>. How to do the same in a more optimal way?

Comment: Why is KMG considered more similar to KG than K or KGG? KGG goes out by the "before" rule, right? But why KG over K? By your definition of "similar" it should be K or not? If it's hamming distance, then it would make sense.

Comment: Hello @Fildor! KMG is exactly as similar to K as to KG, one matching symbol. If several strings are equally similar to the current one, the algorithm has to return the last index (but, of course, before the current index).

Comment: Ah, I see. Now it's clear.

Comment: I think, I would try by building a tree. But I'm still thinking about that and not sure if that would be optimal. So you would have a root with index -1. Then children to that are the single-length strings ... and then go from there. If no children, then new child is similar to parent. Otherwise similar to last child or another match, then game starts over in next level...

Comment: But sorry... What means "children to that are the single-length strings"? Something like LINQ's GroupBy()?

Comment: I really don't think Linq is a good idea here.

Comment: I did not mean exactly the LINQ. But "children to that are the single-length strings" must be built using grouping, or how? Can you explain?

Comment: No. When you add a new node, you start at the root. And if the value has length = 1, it will go to the root's direct children, refer to index -1 and done. Add next array item.